# Drop-down not displaying in IE11 as desired (or how it correctly displays in Chrome/FF)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

Whichever item in the drop-down list is selected, it "stays" in the drop-down display field, and the other choices display above and/or below depending on the current selection location in the list of available choices:

[Initial Dropdown display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OO2A.png)

[When the 3d Choice is selected (or any choice other than the first)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98vI9.png)

[Another example of the 9th choice selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpT3e.png)

I've tried removing the Bootstrap class="form-control", and the behavior persists.

I am required to have the selections always drop below the selection field (which they always do in Chrome/FF - of course), but the main user will be using IE11.

Any help greatly appreciated! Also, since I'm new to posting on S.O., no embedded images (yet!) - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I again try to develop a sample using bootstrap 4. In my testing I noticed that if the Window size is smaller then the size of the dropdown when it get expand then it overlapped.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="drp" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">High Winds</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Utility blackout</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">earthquake</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Flooding major</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Flooding minor</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Malicious cybor</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Malicious physical</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Volcanic eruption</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Winter strom</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tsunami</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Environmental corrosion</a>
     
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e) {

        $('a.active').removeClass('active');

        var $parent = $(this);
        $parent.addClass('active');


  $("#drp").text($(this).text());
       $("#drp").val($(this).text());
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

To solve the issue, you can try to increase the size of the window or try to display the window with fixed size. Then it will display the dropdown properly without any issue.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4; The example you provided is great EXCEPT it doesn't have the selection display field, but rather just the dropdown button.  When using the selection display field, the behavior persists.  After further troubleshooting and removing all css, it appears this may just be how IE11 (and prior?) handles these drop-downs?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I try to update it as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the leg-work and suggestions; even with the display modifications, the behavior persists, regardless whether contained in a modal or full page.  I even stripped out all CSS/Bootstrap, and this seems to be how IE handles the dropdown.

Comment: Actually, this issue is not specific to IE browser. You can notice this thing in any other browser. If you make the model or page bigger then the size of the dropdown then this issue will not occur. If issue is persist at your end means that you did not modify the code properly. You can try to post your sample code. I can try to test it and can try to show how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is the deafualt behavior in IE10/IE11 (though difficult to find hard confirmation in docs).  Here is a link to an older SO post:

[IE10 Select box issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157108/ie10-select-box-issue)

So.......I had to create a custom JQuery function essentially plucking the selection and adding to the top of the list, then replacing it back when another choice is selected.  This then has the dropdown always below the dropdown field.